# WhereBetween does not work correctly in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Records in MySQL database looking like `06/30/1986`. Using format "m/d/Y".

I'm trying to get the data using the function:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereBetween('date', [07/04/1960, 07/04/2016])
            ->get();
```

But records from DB are not displayed with this query.

Comment: `[07/04/1960, 07/04/2016]` what language is this? what type your array elements are? try just pass good string values like `['1960-04-07', '2016-04-07']`

Comment: _Records in MySQL database looking like 06/30/1986_ please check what type your column is? `DATE`? `VARCHAR`?

Comment: VARCHAR, but I tried DATE too.

Comment: why it is `varchar`!? change to `date` if it is not live project yet

Comment: Changed to DATE, changed format to "Y-m-d" and rebuild database, and its working! Thank you!

Comment: you are very welcome :-) good luck with your project!

Comment: Alex, can you please put the correct answer forward, and that might help other people. Also have a look at Carbon, a great php library and works well with Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column type in MySQL DB changed from VARCHAR to DATE, changed format to "Y-m-d", and its working!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$first = Carbon::createFromDate(1960,4,7);
$second = Carbon::createFromDate(2016,4,7);

$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$first->toDateTimeString(), $second->toDateTimeString()])
            ->get();
```